# Too much whitespace at MSO's top

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The new navigation changed the way MSO looks, and left quite a lot of empty whitespace at the top, between the "Top Questions" heading and the buttons:

[image]

Or, to put it more bluntly:

[image]

Perhaps we could move the buttons up next to the "Ask Question" button and save some space?

[image]

Comment: On Newest Questions it shows the question count under the title, so the vertical space kind of makes sense, but they can probably just put "X top questions" or something there to fill the space. Although even then there's too much vertical space. And it just seems redundant to have 2 2-term phrases referring to the same thing that both contain the word "questions".

Comment: In the mobile view on my phone there would be not enough space for all of the buttons to reside on one line.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `m` suffix when linking your images, because that way if people click the images, they are really small

Comment: @Ferrybig it actually does look better without the `m` - thanks

Comment: I see some non free hand tool usage in your circles.

Comment: @Victoria really? That's 100% free hand (with mypaint on Ubuntu 18)

Comment: Wow, then you're quite precise. Well done!

Comment: Be careful not optimizing for the wrong thing. Empty space is an important design element. When you remove it all, you end up with an inscrutable wall of text like the terminal screens still inflicted today upon many hapless bank employees

Comment: Nah, vertical whitespace is overrated.

Comment: On [meta.stackoverflow.com/questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) where would the text "35,545 questions" go? also here is 5 slightly larger buttons instead of 4 there. 

On [meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered) where would the text "7,066 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers" go?

Comment: *“Where would the text go”* – Where it was before this redesign?

Comment: > where would the text "35,545 questions" go? - I'd argue this is not useful information and should just be removed

Comment: @kenwarner on the search page and tagged question lists and such that is shown, and is useful information in many cases. Just because _you_ don't use it does not mean that it is not useful.

Comment: [Feel free to leave your feedback on the MSE post about the new design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/check-out-the-sneak-peek-of-left-nav-new-theme-and-responsiveness)

Comment: @TinyGiant WRT "In the mobile view on my phone there would be not enough space for all of the buttons to reside on one line." - the desktop version and the mobile version look different regardless. Changing (arguably - "fixing") one needn't affect the othert.

Comment: @Mureinik it still has to make sense and look consistent. We don't want stuff jumping from one end of the page to the other when people resize their browser Windows.

Comment: Seems to be just about enough room for a banner ad...

Comment: The new layout looks almost identical to a web page I made in the late 90s, as a hobbyist teenager. It had the very same grotesque frame to the left, the very same compact button menu layout spewed aimlessly somewhere on the top, and it contained copious amounts of unused space. I'm just missing the grey background, blue Times New Roman font for links and the visitor counter. Stack Overflow: now with frames! Disclaimer: must use Netscape 2.0 or later.

Comment: @Lundin - Agree. Next we will see marquee and blink show up for announcements and feature highlighting. #geocities

Comment: @Lundin blunt, but I can't say I complete disagree

Answer (score 13):

I'm not saying this can't be fixed, but please remember that this design is responsive, at least partially to cater to users on screens that are smaller. Moving that content up (as in Pureferret's answer) is *a* solution but it makes it so that the page can't collapse as much before losing the right sidebar. For example:

Here's the site's minimum page width with both sidebars:

[image: Minimum page width with both sidebars, much less white space, tabs are too long to fit between "Top Questions" header and "Ask Question" button]

As you can see, there's not sufficient room between "Top Questions" and "Ask Question" to fit the four tabs "active", "hot", "week", "month".

Collapsing further than this shoves the right sidebar to the bottom of the page... which is (I'm guessing) why the "Ask Question" button *isn't* in the right sidebar any more.

Here's what the page looks like when it's just a touch narrower:

[image: After the right sidebar pops to the bottom of the page, there's a lot of white space again]

If you test this yourself, you'll find the entire right sidebar is hanging out between the page content and the footer.

If a solution can be found that still allows users the full site content - both left and right sidebars and the main page content - that'd be great but I do understand why they made the decision they did about the placement of these tabs.

This gets even more complicated when you're on search results pages, which add the number of results next to the tabs, more tabs, and longer text than "Top Questions".

For example, here's a tag search result for [stackoverflow-for-teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams):

[image: Full width page view shows much more usage of whitespace when content is something other than the Top Questions view]

And, at the narrower page width, this still looks really nice and full, as the long search header wraps to a second line along with the "questions" text moving below the quantity of results:

[image: Narrow width page view shows good wrapping and limited whitespace]

So, for consistency between the different pages, I'm not *actually* sure there's a better solution. Yes, it does look a bit barren on the Top Questions page at wider views but everywhere else it looks good with just enough white space to separate the areas of the header.

Comment: The example from your "a touch narrower" is probably a bug due to using flexbox and having the content display below itself rather than to the side. The content that no longer shows to the right is literally named sidebar.

Comment: Can't we at least left-align them?  Then I wouldn't have that gaping hole in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a mock up of the page without white space:

[image: MSO home page with the 'active', 'hot', 'week', and 'month' filters between the heading 'Top Questions' header and the 'Ask Question' button]

Here is a mock up of the questions page:

[image: MSO question page with the 'newset', 'frequent', 'votes', 'active', and 'unanswered' filters between the heading 'All Questions' header and the 'Ask Question' button. The 'All questions' header has the number of questions below it]

In a narrower profile, they could slide back under the header.

Comment: What about https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions ? Now you have an inconsistent layout.

Comment: @Stijn it was inconsistent before. Better now?

Comment: Yes, better now :) Not a fan of it, but removed the downvote.

Comment: But any smaller width than that and it is unusable. Remember this is supposed to be used on mobile devices as well.

Comment: @TinyGiant they can always slide around based on screen size.

Comment: I really like this suggestion  - clean on the one hand, but not a desert of whitespace on the other.

Answer (score -6):

Here's another possible approach that might be worth considering.

[image: shitty mockup]

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work on the search results page or a lot of others. It might work for the main page but if we're looking for a consistent design, I'm not sure this is a good option.

Comment: @Catija I feel that search result and other pages might be aligned in the same way. It would definitely be atrocious English though since the tabs can represent both sorting and filtering ...

Comment: I don't know why this upsets me so much but it does